# Serializing and Deserializing in Plain Text Format

Tags: java, oop, serialization, deserialization, file-handling

I am making a cricket tournament management system. I has a class named *`Player`* and two child classes *`Batsman`* and *`Bowler`*. The *`Player`* class has following data members:

```
private String name;
private int ID;
private int age;
private int height;
```

now Batsman class has Batsman specific members and Bowler class has some Bowler specific members.

I have an `abstract addRecord` method  in Player class which is implemented in both Batsman and Player class. I want the to use a common file for both child classes in such a way that **ID is not duplicated in the file**.
And then I can retrieve only Batsman's or only Bowler's records from file as needed and make an array of Batsman or Bowler objects from them.

Is there a way to use Class.forName() and then created an instance of that class by dynamically at runtime using a string containing the class name.

Please help!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but you can use instanceof to check if the object is a batsman or bowler after it has been created.

Comment: Write a separate class to provide unique IDs for both `Batsman` and `Bowler` objects.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a Database for that and not a file. - You cant read only some 'records' from a file, because it is not indexed

Comment: @fab i need to use file i want to read the whole line from file and then use split() to get ID and other fields. And also it is a requirement of my Assignment to use File and not the database.

Comment: @MuhammadTayyabSheikh could you pleas make an example, how the objects and the file should look like?

Comment: @fab here is the format of file:  ID|name|age|height|type of player(class name in my case)|whatever|else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This could be a start for you:

```
public class IdCounter {

    private static Integer nextId;

    static int getNextId(){
        if (nextId == null){
            //read file and get highest ID
        }
        return nextId++;
    }
}


public class addRecord {

    private String name;
    private int ID;
    private int age;
    private int height;

    private void saveRecord(){
        if(ID==0){
            ID = IdCounter.getNextId();
        }
    }
}
```

If you working with an UI you may need a thread save solution, with locking...
http://winterbe.com/posts/2015/04/30/java8-concurrency-tutorial-synchronized-locks-examples/

Comment: How does it answer the question?  Question was "Is there a way to use Class.forName() and then created an instance of that class by dynamically at runtime using a string containing the class name."

Comment: @talex the initial question was not asking "Is there a way to use Class.forName()..." ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48017467/revisions